# Redirect any url containing /foo/

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a series of around 400 urls using .htaccess/Apache containing a given /directory/ anywhere in the url to a specific location.

The problem here is that my site is receiving requests for an old site hosted on our servers ip. I've tried manually redirecting the urls but the volume is simply too great.

I've searched but can only find examples for redirecting query strings or files

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if all links have the same directory in there... example store/funstuff/blahblah.php

and funstuff is the directory you are looking for then you could modify your .htaccess file something linke this

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 Options -Multiviews
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} funstuff
 RewriteRule . http://www.gohere.com/
```

Then if you needed to pass more of the URL info you could do the last line like this:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.gohere.com/1$
```

That should get you started... you may need to tweak it slightly.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you processing the redirects in?

You probably need to use a regular expression that searches for the given /directory/.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly and that you are using Apache; [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) should do what you want.

It accepts a regexp for matching and can then redirect to the place you choose.